# value cannot be null with htmlagility pack selectnodes

Tags: html-agility-pack

I have error "Value cannot be null" when taking data from div with htmlagility pack, 
my code is:

```
var varitem = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='title']")
 .SelectMany(x => x.Descendants("div"));
```

I tryed to chek if value is null with code:

```
if (object.ReferenceEquals(doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='title']")
 .SelectMany(x => x.Descendants("div")), null))
```

but again I get same error.

Comment: Debug your code, check if `doc.DocumentNode` is null, or if `doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='title']")` is null...

Comment: Thanks har07, solved, i only ckecked if doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='title']") is null, excluding.SelectMany(x => x.Descendants("div"))